# Intuitive Way to Use JS on Both Front-End and Back-End (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a multiplayer HTML5 game, and have chosen Node.JS so that I can write the game engine and use it both on the client side (For collision detection without network latency) and on the server side (To drive the main game and verify movements and such).

For example, `GameEngine.js` requires `Collision.js`, which requires `Primitives.js`. On my frint-end (for clients) I do this:

```
<script src="js/Primitives.js"></script>
<script src="js/Collision.js"></script>
<script src="js/GameEngine.js"></script>
```

This puts everything in the global scope and I just basically use anything I need:

In `Primitives.js`:

```
class Rect {
  // ...
}
```

In `Collision.js`:

```
class CollisionObject extends Rect {
  // ...
}
```

In Node.JS, things are modular, so I can't just import things like that. My first solution was something like this, if placed at the top of `Collision.js`:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined'){
  const {Rect} = require("./Primitives");
}
```

A solution I quickly abandoned because it obviously only places `Rect` in a scope which immediately dies.

Next, I started using the terrible `global` object and that *works* but I do not approve of this solution. What's the solution here?

I am willing to modify both how the client loads scripts AND how the server loads scripts in order to achieve my dreams.

Comment: Maybe you should be using something like webpack that would allow you to develop cleanly with modules even for front-end code.

Comment: You can just require the primitives multiple times when you want to use them in different files... what exactly is the issue?

Comment: You could use ES modules everywhere; Node has (experimental) support  for them...

Comment: @Kokodoko do you mind elaborating?

Comment: I'm just wondering why you can't put `const {Rect} = require("./Primitives");` above every one of your modules. Why do you think you need the `if` statement?

Comment: @Kokodoko That would break it on client side. Require is node only

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour and use a bundler like webpack as @Mark Meyer suggests.
Your folder structure would look like this:

- client
- common
- server

Whereas the common folder contains the files that are shared by server and client. Instead of using the global scope, you import your files as modules and webpack will create the bundle for you.

You would have a separate webpack configuration file for server and client, but you can setup an automated workflow using npm script where server and client bundles are automatically recompiled on changes (using --watch) and even hot reloaded in the browser.

This may be some overkill for you, but I have created a setup in the past that is isomorphic:

https://github.com/kimgysen/isomorphic-react-setup/tree/master/src

You can get some ideas from it using the webpack configs and npm scripts that you find there.

Comment: While I recognize that this is a decent solution, i was looking for something even simpler.

Comment: Although it may look complicated, once you know how it works, you can make this setup in about 10 minutes. Of course you have to learn how to do it, but you won't regret it afterwards... just my two cents.

Comment: I appreciate that and if I don't find the thing I am looking for, I will probably experiment with webpack

Comment: Cool. Just as an extra: there is merit to bundlers. Changing code in the common code can auto-recompile your bundles client and server side. This saves you a ton of time afterwards. Good luck!

Comment: as I am supporting only the most recent versions of major browsers (I need WebGL and a bunch of modern stuff anyways) and since I am running NJS 13, I have decided to go with ES modules. It's not exactly as simple as I hoped, but pretty close.

Comment: You can load ES6 modules straight into the browser, so you might not even need a bundler, at least while testing things out in the simplest possible way.

Comment: @Kokodoko Yeah but that does not offer a simpler workflow IMO if he means to run the same code server and client side. I use an isomorphic setup, and once setup, every change is just tracked and automatically hot reloaded on both server / client side. You don't lose any time at all.